# when I type "sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl" in linux cmd, it returns empty

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I performed the steps in https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/ to properly install minikube locally in my ubuntu running on my VM:

```
pcname@ubuntu:~$curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
```

also

```
pcname@ubuntu:~$sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

an empty cmd line is returned. When I type `minikube start` as if it is install properly I get the following error:

> minikube v1.22.0 on Ubuntu 20.04   Unable to pick a default
> driver. Here is what was considered, in preference order:
> ▪ docker: Not installed: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
> ▪ kvm2: Not installed: exec: "virsh": executable file not found in $PATH
> ▪ podman: Not installed: exec: "podman": executable file not found in $PATH
> ▪ vmware: Not installed: exec: "docker-machine-driver-vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
> ▪ virtualbox: Not installed: unable to find VBoxManage in $PATH
>
> ❌  Exiting due to DRV_NOT_DETECTED: No possible driver was detected.
> Try specifying --driver, or see
> https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Notice: Before those, I followed all steps in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/ and I installed kubectl and verified it is installed by:

```
pcname@ubuntu:kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe3***************", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
even if the 3 step failed.
```

What is wrong? I am just trying to install kubectl and then minikube. Do I have to install Docker as it is suggested when I type "minikube start" ?

Comment: you do need to install docker. run `curl -L get.docker.com | sh`.

Comment: ...or any of the alternatives that are listed out in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
-sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/minikube to give execute permission to minikube
-minikube version  => It gave the version
-minikube start => it did not work.
-Figured out that I have to install Virtual Box so I typed:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

-minikube start [again] and installation started and goes on without a hitch.